# How to get page title from footer when it’s included as a partial?

Tags: html, twig, markdown, grav

I have a blog page and trying to add a footer as a partial , but the title of the blog page from **footer.md** is not correctly displayed

I’ve this code to the **base.html.twig** :
`{% include 'partials/footer.html.twig' %}`

**pages/footer/default.md**

```
---
title: Footer
routable: false
visible: false
process:
    markdown: true
    twig: true
twig_first: true
---
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
```

**partials/footer.hml.twig:**

```
<section id="footer" class="section bg-gray">
    <section class="container {{ grid_size }}">
      {% set footer_content = pages.find('/footer').content %}
      {% if footer_content %}
        {{ footer_content }}
      {% else %}
        <p><a href="http://getgrav.org">Grav</a> was <i class="fa fa-code"></i> with <i class="fa fa-heart-o pulse "></i> by <a href="https://trilby.media">Trilby Media</a>.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </section>
</section>
```

Whatever the title of blog pages I always have as a title in the footer the title  of the page footer, i.e.  `Footer`

is it possible to have the the title of blog pages ?

Comment: If all you want is to print the title of the current page inside the footer, `{{ page.title }}` in footer.html.twig will do. What is your intention behind using a separate footer page for that?

Comment: My goal is to have different and customizable footers depending on the page model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are parsed upfront, not at the moment when called in Twig using `{% set content = pages.find('/footer') %}`.
During parsing, the context is the page itself, so `{{ page.title }}` inside its Markdown will always refer to the current page object. Hence the value `<h1>Footer</h1>` in your example.

However the Markdown of a page object can be parsed inside Twig using the Grav function `evaluate_twig`. See Grav's docs on [Twig Filters & Functions](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/twig-filters-functions)

For example:

- '/pages/footer/default.md'

  ```
  ---
  title: Footer
  routable: false
  visible: false
  # process:              <-- not needed because we use raw markdown
  #     markdown: true
  #     twig: true
  # twig_first: true
  ---
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
  ```
- Snippet inside 'footer.html.twig'

  ```
  {% set rawMarkdown = pages.find('/footer').rawMarkdown %}
  {{ evaluate_twig(rawMarkdown) }}
  ```
- Result when browsing 'localhost/blog/focus-and-blur' using the 'Blog Site' skeleton

  [image]